# Unable to filter google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, sdk

I am trying to restrict google places auto complete to India,but unable to filter,can someone please suggest help.
My googlemap framework,
      #import

```
     GMS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

        /**
     * The type filters that may be applied to an autocomplete request to          restrict results to different
      * types.
     */
        typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter) {
     /**
      * All results.
     */
    kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter,
    /**
   * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
   */
    kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode,
    /**
   * Geocoding results with a precise address.
   */
       kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterAddress,
     /**
    * Business results.
   */
     kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment,

     /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "sublocality"
   * "postal_code",
   * "country",
   * "administrative_area_level_1",
   * "administrative_area_level_2"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "administrative_area_level_3"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity,
};

/**
 * This class represents a set of restrictions that may be applied to autocomplete requests. This
 * allows customization of autocomplete suggestions to only those places that are of interest.
 */
@interface GMSAutocompleteFilter : NSObject

/**
 * The type filter applied to an autocomplete request to restrict results to different types.
 * Default value is kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter.
 */
@property(nonatomic, assign) GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter type;

/**
 * The country to restrict results to. This should be a ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code (case
 * insensitive). If nil, no country filtering will take place.
 */
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *GMS_NULLABLE_PTR INDIA;


@end

GMS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I am trying to restrict google places auto complete to India,but unable to filter,can someone please suggest help.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
- (NSString* _Nullable) country [read, write, copy]
```

The country to restrict results to.

This should be a ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code (case insensitive). If nil, no country filtering will take place.

For India you should do:

```
  yourFilter.country =@"IN";
```

Here is the list of country [codes.](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm)